# Upgrade from 22.10 to 23.04 breaks WiFi on Thinkpad

Tags: networking, wireless, upgrade, thinkpad, 23.04

My system upgraded, rebooted, but there is no network.
Which packages can I get and install that provide WiFi for a Lenovo Thinkpad carbon with Intel Alder lake-P PCH CNVi WiFi controller ?
Or is there a minimalist Ubuntu iso image of 22.10 I can install and do a recovery from backup and wait til this upgrade path is better sorted?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of these terminal commands: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` and: `sudo dmesg | grep iwl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.